# How to call a method that receives arguments in the Tick event of a Timer in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, timer

I don't know if my title is quite specific, but my problem is that I want to wait 1 sec (1000 ms) to perform an action that is on a method. I haven't used a Timer before, but I see that you do something like:

```
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
```

And then you define your OnTimedEvent method:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

The point is that the method I wanna call receives 5 arguments, and all the examples I've seen use the object source, ElapsedEventArgs e thing. I wanna know how to call a method and send it's arguments after 1 sec is elapsed.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you use, or are you using, .NET 4.5? It has new async features that could come in handy here.

Answer (score 1):

Create a small helper class, with

- fields for the 5 arguments and your final delegate
- a single method of the timer delegate prototype, that calls your final delegate with your 5 arguments (all present in the instance)

Now instantiate it, assign the parameters and set the wrapper method as your timer delegate.

Answer (score 0):

And the problem is...

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
    MyMethod(par1, par2, parn..);
}
```

Comment: And how do par1... come in there?

Comment: Well, I can't tell, you're the software architect here, I don't know! :-) You asked how to call a method.. Normally you use members in the same class to hold those values.

Comment: The OQ was in essence, how to pass 5 parameters to a timer delegate.

Comment: Wich timer? Windows.Forms.Timer? Just create five variables in the form hosting the timer, assign them some values and call your method. I don't see the problem.

Comment: I personally consider it extremly bad style to use something like a form-global variable for such a task. It also breaks catastrophically in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: With such information is hard to give a better advise. Also notice that winforms are single threaded by design.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about extending the timer to do what you want? Here is some sample code:

```
 class Program
{



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TimerEx timer = new TimerEx(1000, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        timer.ElapsedEx += new ElapsedExEventHandler(timer_ElapsedEx);
        timer.Start();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void timer_ElapsedEx(object sender, ElapsedEventArgsEx e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.P1.ToString());
    }



    public delegate void ElapsedExEventHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgsEx e);

    public class TimerEx : System.Timers.Timer
    {
        private ElapsedEventArgsEx e;

        public TimerEx(double interval, object p1, object p2, object p3, object p4, object p5) : base(interval)
        {
            e = new ElapsedEventArgsEx() { P1 = p1, P2 = p2, P3 = p3, P4 = p4, P5 = p5 };
            this.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerEx_Elapsed);
        }

        void TimerEx_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.OnElapsedEx(e.SignalTime);
        }



        public event ElapsedExEventHandler ElapsedEx;
        private void OnElapsedEx(DateTime signalTime)
        {
            var handler = this.ElapsedEx;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                e.SignalTime = signalTime;
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ElapsedEventArgsEx : EventArgs
    {
        public ElapsedEventArgsEx()
        {

        }

        public DateTime SignalTime { get; set; }
        public object P1 { get; set; }
        public object P2 { get; set; }
        public object P3 { get; set; }
        public object P4 { get; set; }
        public object P5 { get; set; }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous delegate.

Lambda syntax is the easiest way to make one

```
aTimer.Elapsed += (source, args) => OnTimedEvent(source, args, extraarg1, extraarg2 /* etc */);
```

But you can use the older syntax also:

```
aTimer.Elapsed += delegate (object source, ElapsedEventArgs args) { OnTimedEvent(source, args, extraarg1, extraarg2 /* etc */); };
```